# Deploying war hangs using tomcat maven plugin

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat6

I am trying to use maven to deploy a war file to tomcat after the war file has been built by maven on a separate occasion. I use `mvn tomcat:deploy-only -X`, but maven says the war file is being deployed and then it just continues to say that and never stops (I am sure of this as just for kicks I let it go over lunch once to make sure it wasn't some 15 min process so it's not in issue of patience).

Here is the output from maven:

```
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <charset default-value="ISO-8859-1">${maven.tomcat.charset}</charset>
  <contextFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
  <ignorePackaging default-value="false">${tomcat.ignorePackaging}</ignorePackaging>
  <mode default-value="war">${maven.tomcat.mode}</mode>
  <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
  <password>${tomcat.password}</password>
  <path default-value="/${project.artifactId}">${maven.tomcat.path}</path>
  <server>${maven.tomcat.server}</server>
  <tag>${maven.tomcat.tag}</tag>
  <update default-value="false">${maven.tomcat.update}</update>
  <url default-value="http://localhost:8080/manager">${maven.tomcat.url}</url>
  <username>${tomcat.username}</username>
  <version>${plugin.version}</version>
  <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy-only (default-cli) @ mn-stateadvantagewar ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy-only from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4aad3ba4]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy-only' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) charset = ISO-8859-1
[DEBUG]   (f) contextFile = C:\dev\myApp\mywar\target\myapp\META-INF\context.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) ignorePackaging = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mode = war
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = war
[DEBUG]   (f) path = /mn-stateadvantagewar
[DEBUG]   (f) update = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = http://localhost:8080/manager
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 1.1
[DEBUG]   (f) warFile = C:\dev\myApp\mywar\target\mn-stateadvantage.war
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/mn-stateadvantagewar
[DEBUG] No server specified for authentication - using defaults
```

We use tomcat 6.0 so I am willing to use some tomcat6-maven-plugin if you think that will help, but I think this is an issue that does not have to do with the version of tomcat.  It is probably something more basic that I am just not aware of.

Also, if there is a better way to tell what is happening once the "deploy" kicks off, let me know.  The -X argument only shows what is above.  No errors, never finishes.

Comment: Is there a reason for using an old Plugin (org.codehaus...). Is the old location. The new location for the tomcat maven plugin is http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html ? Apart from that does the server.log or catalina.out say something during the deployment ?(errors/warning)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it simply by restarting tomcat.

I saw these lines in localhost.{date}.log but was never able to track it down:

```
Feb 03, 2014 10:40:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Manager: deploy: Deploying web application at '/phisApi'
Feb 03, 2014 10:40:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Manager: Uploading WAR file to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/phisApi.war
```